# how to select columns from 2 tables that are not related directly?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables A ,B ,C

TABLE A

```
TABLE_NAME|table_number
   soho        20  
   foho        30
   joho        40
```

TABLE B

```
TABLE_ID | TABLE_NAME
    1         soho
    2         foho
    3         joho
```

TABLE C

```
 TABLE_ID | TABLE_VALUES
      1           xx
      1           yy
      2           hh
      3           no
      3           bb
```

what I want to do is pass table_name as `:paramter` from  and get `table_values` from table c, like this if i pass soho

```
TABLE_NAME| TABLE_VALUES
    SOHO           xx
    SOHO           yy
```

this is my try but I get the `table_value` for all tables

```
select a.table_name , c.table_value
from a , b , c 
where a.table_name= :myParamter
and 
b.table_id= c.table_id
```

the output of my query is like this

```
ABLE_NAME| TABLE_VALUES
  SOHO           xx
  SOHO           yy
  SOHO           hh
  SOHO           no
  SOHO           bb
```

Comment: do not join tableA. join only table B and C

Comment: threre are table names that may not exist in table b

Comment: Who taught you to use comma-separated joins? They were made redundant in **1992**. Use ANSI joins instead: `from b join c using (table_id)` or `from b join c on c.table_id = b.table_id`.

Answer (score 5):

```
select b.table_name , c.table_value
from b inner join c 
on
b.table_id= c.table_id
where  b.table_name= :myParamter
```

Comment: there are table names that may not exist in table b

Comment: Then how are you going to get table_values for them ? you only have IDs in Table B and Table C.

Comment: As per your tables If name is not present in table B then he/she will not have table_id and if there is no table_id then no value.

Comment: That should be `from b inner join c on b.table_id = c.table_id where b.table_name = :myParamter` for readability. The table name is not criteria on how to join table c.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner good point about readability, answer updated. But it works both ways.

Answer (score 1):

> Table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEA
(
  TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(64),
  TABLE_NUMBER NUMBER(18)
);

CREATE TABLE TABLEB
(
  TABLE_ID NUMBER(18),
  TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(64)
);

CREATE TABLE TABLEC
(
  TABLE_ID NUMBER(18),
  TABLE_VALUES VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

> Data Inserts

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES('soho',20);
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES('foho',30);
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES('joho',40);


INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES(1,'soho');
INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES(2, 'foho');
INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES(3, 'joho');


INSERT INTO TABLEC VALUES(1, 'xx');
INSERT INTO TABLEC VALUES(1,'yy');
INSERT INTO TABLEC VALUES(2, 'hh');
INSERT INTO TABLEC VALUES(3, 'no');
INSERT INTO TABLEC VALUES(3, 'bb');
```

> Query -

```
select b.table_name, c.table_values
from tableb b inner join tablec c
on b.table_id = c.table_id
inner join tablea a
on a.table_name = b.table_name
and b.table_name = 'soho'
;
```

> Output

```
TABLE_NAME,TABLE_VALUES
soho,yy
soho,xx
```